# OO design - switching between modes

Tags: oop

I am designing an application to monitor availability of components.

So first of all I'd have a **Scheduler** to run the availability checks (e.g. **Jobs**) in regular intervals.

There are a couple of components (and more are expected to be supported in future) to be monitored and for each of them there is a different way to find out if it's available or not.

So I was thinking I'd do an abstract **ComponentStatusVerifier** class with an **abstract boolean** method called **verify** and for each of the components I'd create a subclass to implement the specific verifying strategy.

The problem is a little bit more complicated though. The application is supposed to support running on two different platforms (e.g. servers, and there is a potential of supporting more platforms in future) and the set of components to be monitored depends on the platform where the application is deployed.

It is possible to either build the application separately for every destination server or let the application know where it's running through the configuration - so the problem is not how to make the application be aware of where it's running.

**The question I have is how to complement the design of the application to support these run modes and at the same time to not lose the high cohesion of the individual classes.**

Comment: What kind of applications are we talking about? Batches, web applications, applications without a GUI, etc.

Comment: It will be a simple simple application running directly on the target server, communicating with the components either through local commands or using HTTP requests. It will have no user interface - all configuration will be done on startup through a configuration file. It will run in a loop, doing the availability checks in fixed intervals and sleep in the meantime. It will probably be run as a Windows service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your `ComponentStatusVerifier` that checks *one* component also check whether it *should* verify at runtime based on where it's running. Your `verify` method should be extended a bit to support it: it should receive the relevant *parameters*: like the *platform* the application is in:

```
interface ComponentStatusVerifier {
  boolean verify(VerificationParameters parameters);
}

interface VerificationParameters {
  Platform getPlatform();
}

enum Platform {
  PLATFORM1,
  PLATFORM2 // ...
}
```

Also, from your description it seems that some diagnostic information would be important, instead of a simple `boolean` result. For that, I'd create a message list with information that the *verifier* can report on, something like this:

```
interface ComponentStatusVerifier {
  VerificationResults verify(VerificationParameters parameters);
}

interface VerificationResults {
  boolean succeeded();
  Iterable<Message> getMessages();
}

interface Message {
  string getDescription();
  MessageType getType();
}

enum MessageType {
  INFO,
  WARNING,
  ERROR
}
```

(Note that I've used interfaces and enums just to show the concepts, adapt as appropriate...)

A verifier that's running on a platform it doesn't support could do this:

```
class Platform1SomeComponentVerifier implements ComponentStatusVerifier {
  @Override
  public VerificationResults verify(VerificationParameters parameters) {
    VerificationResults results = new ...
    if (parameters.getPlatform() != Platform.PLATFORM1) {
      results.addMessage(
        new InfoMessage("Skipping verification of component, platform is not PLATFORM1"));
      return results;
    }

    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was aiming at. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, by your description it sounds like you should have a **ComponentStatusVerifier**.

That object should hold a **ComponentConnectorClass**.

The **ComponentConnectorClass** should hold a list of **Verifier** classes that will run and check all the things you need to verify.

Or you should be able to run the **ComponentConnectorClass** and then give it a list of **Verifier** classes to work with.

Comment: So the ComponentStatusVerifier is the class to represent the run mode, e.g. the set of components to be checked? The Verifier is a class to actually verify a single component? What is then the ComponentConnectorClass good for? How would I represent the individual component sets - should I subclass the ComponentStatusVerifier for each supported set?

Comment: the ComponentConnectorClass would be used to connect to the different servers. but again, it's just a suggestion, there no "right" way to design ... only alot of wrong ways :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to tackle this problem.

You can configure all the applications to verify in your monitoring application. This is flexible and extensible up until a certain point.

Another way (although a lot more intrusive) is to have your applications to be checked register themselves in the monitoring application. This way the only thing your monitor has to do is call the applications that were registered. This is also very flexible and extensible since your monitoring application can be "dumb".

I would suggest using the proposed architecture of Yochai and have multiple Verifier classes each implementing another way of verifying, albeit a http request, rmi, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can write [proxy class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) to do the coding necessary to check if it is alive.

```
    // Remote box
    class remoteObject {
        int check() {
            // I write code for this universe 
            // is multiverse true ?
        }
    }

    class remoteObjectProxy {
        remoteObject y;
        int check() {
            // do things necessary
            return y.check();
        }
    }
```

```
    // Your box
    class localProxy {
        remoteObjectProxy z;
        int check() {
            // do things necessary
            return z.check();
        }
    }
```